# How come i can't add all the nodes from Stack

Tags: data-structures

```
Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stack.push(new Node(i));
        }
```

when i try:

```
while(stack != null){
    double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());}
```

it throws me EmptyStackException

when I try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());
    }
```

it does not print out all the nodes(only half of them)

Answer (score 0):

The first example is wrong because you're comparing the `stack` reference to `null`, but you mean to check its size:

```
// Wrong
while(stack != null){
  double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());
}

// Right
while(stack.size() > 0) {
  double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());
}
```

This is because even when the stack is empty, the reference to the empty structure still exists and isn't `null`.

The second example is wrong because you're popping from the stack inside your loop, so its size is shrinking:

```
// Wrong
for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
  double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());
}

// Right
int length = stack.size();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  double_list.add_tail(stack.pop());
}
```

Without this change, `stack.size()` is evaluated after the `pop()`, so it will be one element smaller. Meanwhile, `i` is incremented. The first iteration compares `i=0` to `stack.size()=10`, the next `i=1` to `stack.size()=9` and so on. It stops when `i=5` and `stack.size()=5`. Setting `length=stack.size();` before the loop fixes `length` to `10` regardless of future changes to `stack.size()`.